# Appending 3d array into 4d array, the 4th dimension being number of 3D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, numpy

In the process of MRI image analysis, I would like to "mask" a time-series image as a part of pre-processing. Time-series Images are 4D (the 4th dimension is time at which the image was taken- x,y,z,t). Since my mask is a 3D array (x,y,z) I would like to duplicate 3D for all time-series images so that I can mask the 4D array without any problem regarding different size. `numpy.ma` can not broadcast what I have in mind and I always get the error of size differences. So is duplicating a 3d array to 4d array efficient? Do you think I can perform another efficient way without doing this?

Comment: Can you give a quick example of a sample input and desired output?  It would help (some of us) be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without more detail. But it sounds like you're confronting a problem like this:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(2 * 3 * 4 * 5).reshape(2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> mask = a[0,...] > 29
>>> numpy.ma.MaskedArray(a, mask)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/
                 Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", 
                 line 2706, in __new__
    raise MaskError, msg % (nd, nm)
numpy.ma.core.MaskError: Mask and data not compatible: data size is 120, 
                         mask size is 60.
```

A simple solution (if that is indeed your problem) would be to expand the mask along the time dimension using `concatenate`. So for example, if the first axis is your time dimension, you could do this (where `reps` is equal to the number of times you want to repeat the mask; in this case, `2`):

```
>>> numpy.ma.MaskedArray(a, numpy.concatenate([mask] * reps, axis=0))
masked_array(data =
 [[[[0 1 2 3 4]
   [5 6 7 8 9]
   [10 11 12 13 14]
   [15 16 17 18 19]]

  [[20 21 22 23 24]
   [25 26 27 28 29]
   [-- -- -- -- --]
   [-- -- -- -- --]]

  [[-- -- -- -- --]
   [-- -- -- -- --]
   [-- -- -- -- --]
   [-- -- -- -- --]]]


 [[[60 61 62 63 64]
   [65 66 67 68 69]
   [70 71 72 73 74]
   [75 76 77 78 79]]

  [[80 81 82 83 84]
   [85 86 87 88 89]
   [-- -- -- -- --]
   [-- -- -- -- --]]

  [[-- -- -- -- --]
   [-- -- -- -- --]
   [-- -- -- -- --]
   [-- -- -- -- --]]]],
             mask =
 [[[[False False False False False]
   [False False False False False]
   [False False False False False]
   [False False False False False]]

  [[False False False False False]
   [False False False False False]
   [ True  True  True  True  True]
   [ True  True  True  True  True]]

  [[ True  True  True  True  True]
   [ True  True  True  True  True]
   [ True  True  True  True  True]
   [ True  True  True  True  True]]]


 [[[False False False False False]
   [False False False False False]
   [False False False False False]
   [False False False False False]]

  [[False False False False False]
   [False False False False False]
   [ True  True  True  True  True]
   [ True  True  True  True  True]]

  [[ True  True  True  True  True]
   [ True  True  True  True  True]
   [ True  True  True  True  True]
   [ True  True  True  True  True]]]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```